# Is there a way to use a different URL structure for static pages in WordPress 2.9?

Tags: wordpress

I have **WP 2.9** installed on an **IIS 7** server. Permalinks works with the `URL Rewrite add-on` for **IIS**, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use different permalink structures for pages and posts. For instance:

Pages would be: `www.url.com/$pagetitle/`
Blog posts would be: `www.url.com/blog/$entrytitle/`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Standard wordpress permalinks have page titles without dates, and you can also get rid of the date in posts: [Customize Your Dated WordPress Permalinks - Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/06/permalink-evolution-customize-and-optimize-your-dated-wordpress-permalinks/).

And get rid of the category base, too: [Wordpress Supplies » Wordpress Plugins » WP No Category Base](http://wordpresssupplies.com/wordpress-plugins/no-category-base/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is actually the default behavior if you use a custom permalink (at least on Apache... it might be different in IIS).